# Python loop with lists

Tags: python, for-loop, python-3.x

I was writing some Python 3.2 code and this question came to me:

I've got these variables:

```
# a list of xml.dom nodes (this is just an example!)
child_nodes = [node1, node2, node3]
# I want to add every item in child_node into this node (this also a xml.dom Node)
parent = xml_document.createElement('TheParentNode')
```

This is exactly what I want to do:

```
for node in child_nodes:
    if node is not None:
        parent.appendChild(node)
```

I wrote it in one line like this:

```
[parent.appendChild(c) for c in child_nodes if c is not None]
```

I'm not going to use the list result at all, I only need the appendChild to do its work.

I'm not a very experienced python programmer, so I wonder which one is better?
I like the single line solution, but I would like to know from experienced python programmers:

Which one is better, in a context of either code beauty/maintainability) and performance/memory use.

Answer (score 8):

The former is preferable in this situation.

The latter is called a [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) and creates a new `list` object full of the results of each call to `parent.appendChild(c)`. *And then discards it*.

However, if you *want* to make a `list` based on this kind of iteration, then you should certainly employ a list comprehension.

Answer (score 0):

The question of code beauty/maintainability is a tricky one. It's really up to you and whoever you work with to decide.

For a long time I was uncomfortable with list comprehensions and so on and preferred writing it the first way because it was easier for me to read. Some people I work with, however, prefer the second method.

Comment: Not if it only uses the side effects.